# How to merge two ontologies in Protege

Tags: sparql, ontology, protege

I'm new to using Protege. I'm using two small owl files, both containing one super class and two sub classes. Both the ontologies are exactly same except for the class names. I imported both the files into a new file and merged one ontology to the other using refactor menu. I used "equivalent to" to map the corresponding classes of the ontologies and did the same for the properties. I want the SPARQL queries to fetch results from both the ontologies. How should I proceed?

Comment: Which results? As far as I understand, you merged both ontologies into a new one and connected classes and properties. Now it's not clear which SPARQL query do you use.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use queries to to get results from the merged ontology. Even after merging I have to use union in the sparql queries to get union of results from both ontologies although I have connected their properties. What I want is a single statement in "WHERE" clause to fetch results for the equivalent properties of both the ontologies.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge Ontology with Protege-OWL API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583312/merge-ontology-with-protege-owl-api)

Answer (score 2):

There is an option `Refactor->Merge ontologies`, may be helpful?

[image]